# prevent elements from shrinking

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to code this discover menu section on my website everything is going well except one thing which is when I click the `View more` button the Js gets activated but the items shrinks, I don't know why i have tried to put the width as 100% but it doesn't work. I've searched here on stack overflow a little bit but i didn't find anything helpful
here is my code:

```css
.discover-ou-menu{
position: relative;

}
.section-heading{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
text-transform:capitalize;
margin: 0;
}
.section-heading::after{
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  left: 41rem;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff9900;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}
/* .dom-container{
  position: relative;
} */
.nav-menu{
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 16px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.nav-menu-item{
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.menu{
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.img-menu{
height: 200px;}
.menu-price{
font-size: 30px;
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
}
.hide{
  display: none;
  transition: 5s ease;
}
#table{
  display: table;
}
.tr{
    display: table-row;
}
.td{
    display: table-cell;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <section class="discover-our-menu">
    <h1 class="section-heading">discover our menu</h1>
    <nav class="nav-menu">
      <a href="#" class="nav-menu-item">main</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-menu-item">desserts</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-menu-item">drinks</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="table">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
          <img src="images/discover our menu/menu1.png" class="img-menu" alt="">
          <div class="menu">
            <h2 class="menu-title">1. Ricotta and strawberry tiramisu</h2>
            <p class="menu-description">A silky tiramisu made with ricotta and fresh strawberries <br>egg | sugar | milk | mascarpone | coffee | brandy | cocoa | vanilla </p>
            <p class="menu-price">30.00$</p>
          </div>
          <!--td1 end-->
        </div>
        <div class="td">
          <img src="images/discover our menu/menu2.png" class="img-menu" alt="">
          <div class="menu">
            <h2 class="menu-title">2. Halloumi and camembert salad</h2>
            <p class="menu-description">A silky tiramisu made with ricotta and fresh strawberries <br>egg | sugar | milk | mascarpone | coffee | brandy | cocoa | vanilla </p>
            <p class="menu-price">30.00$</p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!--td2 end-->

      </div>
      <!--End of row1-->
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
          <img src="images/discover our menu/menu3.png" class="img-menu" alt="">
          <div class="menu">
            <h2 class="menu-title">3. Kelp and morel salad</h2>
            <p class="menu-description">A silky tiramisu made with ricotta and fresh strawberries <br>egg | sugar | milk | mascarpone | coffee | brandy | cocoa | vanilla </p>
            <p class="menu-price">30.00$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="td">
          <img src="images/discover our menu/menu4.png" class="img-menu" alt="">
          <div class="menu">
            <h2 class="menu-title">4. Kelp and morel salad</h2>
            <p class="menu-description">A silky tiramisu made with ricotta and fresh strawberries <br>egg | sugar | milk | mascarpone | coffee | brandy | cocoa | vanilla </p>
            <p class="menu-price">30.00$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end row2-->
      <div class="hide">

      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
          <img src="images/discover our menu/menu1.png" class="img-menu" alt="">
          <div class="menu">
            <h2 class="menu-title">1. Ricotta and strawberry tiramisu</h2>
            <p class="menu-description">A silky tiramisu made with ricotta and fresh strawberries <br>egg | sugar | milk | mascarpone | coffee | brandy | cocoa | vanilla </p>
            <p class="menu-price">30.00$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="td">
          <img src="images/discover our menu/menu2.png" class="img-menu" alt="">
          <div class="menu">
            <h2 class="menu-title">2. Halloumi and camembert salad</h2>
            <p class="menu-description">A silky tiramisu made with ricotta and fresh strawberries <br>egg | sugar | milk | mascarpone | coffee | brandy | cocoa | vanilla </p>
            <p class="menu-price">30.00$</p>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <!--End of row3-->
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
          <img src="images/discover our menu/menu3.png" class="img-menu" alt="">
          <div class="menu">
            <h2 class="menu-title">3. Kelp and morel salad</h2>
            <p class="menu-description">A silky tiramisu made with ricotta and fresh strawberries <br>egg | sugar | milk | mascarpone | coffee | brandy | cocoa | vanilla </p>
            <p class="menu-price">30.00$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="td">
          <img src="images/discover our menu/menu4.png" class="img-menu" alt="">
          <div class="menu">
            <h2 class="menu-title">4. Kelp and morel salad</h2>
            <p class="menu-description">A silky tiramisu made with ricotta and fresh strawberries <br>egg | sugar | milk | mascarpone | coffee | brandy | cocoa | vanilla </p>
            <p class="menu-price">30.00$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<span class="view" onclick="show()">View more +</span>
</div>
  </section>
  <script>
    function show(){
      document.querySelector(".hide").style.display="block";
      document.querySelector(".hide").style.width="888px";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

here are some screenshots of "**before**" i click the view more button and "**after**"

**before**
[image]

**after**

[image]

Comment: Would you add a before/after screenshot so we can see what you're talking about?

Comment: @BryceHowitson done i have added some screenshots check them they are up and thank youin advance

Comment: html probably does not like the fact that the TR is not a child of the Table

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. Are you talking about how the added content appears to fit into one column instead of filling the full width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a class on the main element and nth child to hide it instead of wrapping them.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.querySelector('.table').classList.toggle('limited');
})
```

```css
.table.limited .tr:nth-of-type(1n+4) {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="table limited">
  <div class="tr">1
  </div>
  <div class="tr">2
  </div>
  <div class="tr">3
  </div>
  <div class="tr">4
  </div>
  <div class="tr">5
  </div>
  <div class="tr">6
  </div>
</div>
<button class="more">more</button>
```

with animation

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.table').classList.toggle('limited');
})
```

```css
.table.limited .tr:nth-of-type(1n+4) {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.table .tr:nth-of-type(1n+4) {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
  max-height: 100em;
}
```

```html
<div class="table limited">
  <div class="tr">1
  </div>
  <div class="tr">2
  </div>
  <div class="tr">3
  </div>
  <div class="tr">4
  </div>
  <div class="tr">5
  </div>
  <div class="tr">6
  </div>
</div>
<button class="more">more</button>
```

Comment: can you explain to me why you puted (1n+4) to the CSS :nth-of-type() Selector sorry i'm new to this selector just now i read about it in w3schools but i still don't know why you puted this formula and thank you in advance

Comment: 1n is how to repeat and the 4 is the start index. So if you want more rows to show, than increase the 4 to a bigger number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: sorry but your solution didn't work i just get the 8 rows without any hiding

Comment: Did you add the class? I added `limited` to the table element

Comment: yes i did i checked twice but it didn't work i will provide an executed version of my code check it up

Comment: My code used a class, yours used an id. So the selector in mine does not match yours. `.table.limited` would be `#table.limited` in yours...

Comment: sorry if i bothered but i wanna add some animation so i tried the transition property but it didn't work can you tell me how?

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
.tr {
    display: table-row;
}
```

with this

```
.tr {
    display: table-row;
    float: left;
}
```

then try it